# Query an audio file from my database to PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql, audio

I uploaded `mp3` file to my database. I made a table with an `id` column and `file` column. I uploaded the `mp3` file in the `file` column as `LONGBLOB` using phpMyAdmin.

```
CREATE TABLE voices
(
id int(5),
file longblob
);
```

How can I retrieve it in an HTML audio tag? 
I know I should add more columns to give more info to the files I uploaded but this is like just a test.

Comment: Is there a reason why your mp3 need to live in the DB? (ie. replication?) If not, I'd be easier for you to simply store in your database the path where the file can be found. This way you'd only need to put that path into your HTML5 video control.

Comment: because my supervisor told me that everything should be on the database since it's gonna be an online website ,, i told him about this method he said to try to find a way .. and i've been looking for a method for a week ,, i don't have much time

Comment: Suggestion, upload the audio files in folder and then insert the path (directory) in the table. I will be easier to manage

Comment: @hasumedic seems like i'm gonna so that ,, do you know any of an online something to upload my files and to give me a direct link for them ?

Comment: @Dee994 please have a look at my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uploading MP3 or images into a database is generally considered a bad idea, unless when those databases are specifically designed to serve that type of content or you have a very specific (and good) reason for doing so.

Having said that, you can indeed upload content such as MP3's into database's BLOB fields by serialising the MP3, but you'd be stretching MySQL and causing unnecessary delays to move stuff in and out the database to serve the content.

What you could do instead, would be to use your database as a *pointer* to where the real content is. Now, the architecture for this really depends on what's the scale that you're going to be operating at. I'll give you some ideas depending on that scale:

**1. (very) Low traffic**

If you are not expecting too much traffic and your application is running in a single web server, you can probably do with uploading the content into a folder where your web server has read access to and serve the content from there. That could be even within your application directories:

app_folder/media/mp3/*your.mp3*

Which you could then serve from your HTML5:

```
<source src="http://your_app_domain/media/mp3/your.mp3" type='audio/mp3' />
```

In this case, you'd only need to upload the MP3 files into the *media/mp3/* folder and store in the database either the MP3's filename *your.mp3* or the whole path *media/mp3/your.mp3* depending if your application needs some logic to build the whole path to the files or if they are all in the same place.

**2. Moderate traffic**

If you have moderate traffic, the problem is pretty much the same, but with the caveat that you won't probably be running your application from a single web server. What that means in practice, is that if you allow for MP3 content to be uploaded and then served, you'll need to make it available to all web servers as soon as possible if not instantly.

The quick and easy way to do this, would be to store the files into some sort of [SAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storage_area_network), which would allow you to store your files in a network shared disk which would make it available to all web servers at once. But this solution feels a bit "DIY" these days, and the trend is to see more and more architectures using the cloud for static content storage.

Which brings me to the next option, which would be to store your MP3's in [Amazon S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) or similar. For doing that, you'd need to use the [AmazonSDK](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/) to upload content into a S3 Bucket. It's pretty much the same like a file system, so in your database you'll still need to store either the filename or the whole path where you stored it. Then to use it in your audio control, you'd need to build the URL joining the S3 Bucket URL with your database stored path:

```
<source src="https://mybucket.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/path/to.mp3" type='audio/mp3' />
```

**3. Heavy traffic**

Finally, if you are under a lot of traffic, the best advice is to put your assets behind a [CDN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network). The solution is pretty much the same as per the moderate traffic one, but caching your MP3s will save you tons of database queries to retrieve where your MP3s are located and also allow your website to serve content much faster, since the CDN can deliver the content from data centres close to where your users are located.

Comment: thank you ! i think i'll do your first solution, you've been a great help ! thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You can provide base64 encoded multimedia data as inline content:

```
<audio controls src="data:audio/mp3;base64,T2dnUwACAAAAAAAAAAA+..........+fm5nB6slBlZ3Fcha363d5ut7u3ni1rLoPf728l3KcK" />
```

Using a little helper function it's easily integrated into your html output:

```
function getEmbeddedAudioSrc($type, $data) { 
   return 'data:audio/' . $type . ';base64,' . base64_encode($data); 
}

echo '<audio controls src="' . getEmbeddedAudioSrc('mp3', $row['file']) . '">';
```

Usage of this method should normally be limited to rather small audio files. In any other case it's better to write the audio file to disc and simply just use ordinary urls for reference.